# Get ibeacon major and minor id from another Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I'm using the CLLocationManager in a Viewcontroller for monitoring iBeacons. It's working, but when i'm going to another Viewcontroller i need to get the actuall monitoring data from the parent ViewController. If I'm correct i need to make a singleton? (Sorry if I'm not so specific. I'm really newbie is objective-C).

Comment: A singleton would work, but it may be overkill.  @Danilo has a perfectly good alternative in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the child VC create a property like this :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id iBeaconData;
```

and in the implementation :

```
- (void)setIBeaconData:(id)iBeaconData
{
    _iBeaconData = iBeaconData;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // TODO: change your UI here
    });
}
```

and set this property when your parent receive ibeacons data.

Comment: And i have to set that _ibeaconData property in the parent VC didRangeBeacons method? Could you give me an example? sorry...

Comment: in your parent, after VC child is instantiated, and that having this property iBeaconData, you will set the this property childVC.iBeaconData = you-beacon-data, this triggers the process that I described above